# DevExtreme - 3rd Party PhoneGap/Cordova Plugins

Tags: cordova, devexpress, phonegap-plugins, devextreme

I'm using DevExtreme (DevExpress mobile) within VS2013 to develop a mobile website that we then compile down to native ios and Android apps. 
I need to use one of the [plugins](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins) within my project for when we compile to an ios App. I can't find any good documentation on how to do this. I can find the code for the plugins (i.e. https://github.com/hazemhagrass/phonegap-background), but can't see how to incorporate and use this within my DevExtreme project.

I believe I'm supposed to add the following line to my config.xml file:

```
<plugin name="com.badrit.backgroundjs" spec="0.1.0" source="pgb" />
```

I do this and then add the required JS files to my project to use, but when running the I get an error as the plugin requires Cordova JS methods to be defined and my cordova.js file is empty. I believe DevExtreme populates the cordova file when compiling to a native app, per the comment in the file:

> // This is a fake cordova.js file. It will be replaced with a file
>   specific to the platform and version when building the native package.

Does anyone know how to include these plugins within a DevExtreme project and then how you use them once they are running?

Comment: Have you seen this article - [Packaging Tools](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/VS_Integration/Packaging_Tools/) ? Probably it will be helpful.

Comment: Yes thanks - I had read that. Either I'm missing something, or it doesn't show you how to use the plugins? It tells you to include the <gap:package.. line in the config, but that doesn't actually include any other code files in your project, therefore when trying to use the functionality (i.e call one the functions from the lib you are trying to use) it fails with "function undefined" error. I'm probably missing something basic here.

Comment: Are you trying to test your application in Visual Studio or are you actually creating a mobile app package and deploying it to a device?

Comment: I'm trying to test my appllication in VS. Can I not do that then?

Answer (score 2):

For including a 3rd-party plugin you have to do these steps:

1. Find the plugin name and add that line to the "config.xml" file of
   your project as dear @Ben did in his project.
2. Then right click on your project name in the solution explorer and
   Build Application Template... then choose platform and download the
   package that you want to add to your project.

I guess you missed the second step.